# Orthonormal basis for $L^2(R^d)$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, orthonormal

There is a classical example that the set of exponential functions of the form $\{ e^{2\pi i \lambda t } : \lambda \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}$ is an orthonormal basis (ONB) for $L^2[0,1]$.  <s>And due to the $1$-periodicity of the expoenential it is also an ONB for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.</s>

Is it correct to assume that $\{ e^{2\pi i \langle \lambda, t \rangle } : \lambda \in \mathbb{Z}^d \}$ is an ONB for **edit** ${L^2[0,1]^d}$ (not ${L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}$) where $\langle \lambda, t \rangle$ is the euclidian inner product between $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $t = (t_1,\ldots,t_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d$ using vector notation.

<s>I'm thinking that one can restrict the domain from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $[0,1]^d$ due to the $1$-periodicity of the exponential,</s> and I have shown orthogonality and basis property up to dimension 2, but the terms double in size when i increase the dimension.
Is there a nice general way this can be proven for $d$ dimensions for both orthogonality and the basis property, or is my assumption simply wrong to begin with?

Note that I'm not allowing for any flexibility in terms of shifting $\mathbb{Z}$ with a real number $\alpha$, i.e $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}+\alpha$, as that increases the complexity dramatically in the higher dimensions. I only consider $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I don't exactly understand your "periodicity" argument. $e^{2\pi i n x}$ is not even an element of $L^2(\Bbb R)$. If you want a Hilbert basis for $L^2(\Bbb R)$, you need some workaround. Namely you could consider something like $E_{m,n}(x)=\begin{cases}e^{2\pi inx}&\text{if }m\le x <m+1\\ 0&\text{if }x<m\lor x\ge m+1\end{cases}$, indexed over $(m,n)\in\Bbb Z^2$.

Comment: By periodicity i mean the fact that in dimension one $e_\lambda (t+1) = e^{2\pi i \lambda(t+1)}=e^{2 \pi i \lambda t}e^{2 \pi i \lambda} = e^{2 \pi i \lambda t } = e_\lambda (t) $. So instead of considering all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, we can instead restrict to the interval $[0,1]$.
And I agree that $e^{2\pi it}$ is not a member of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, but is a however member of $L^2[0,1]$. I should have seen the first part, but then I can't fathom why one would consider $t\in\mathbb{R}$ in the first place and then restrict to $[0,1]$ if not to make an ONB for the whole of  $\mathbb{R}$ in the end

Comment: Its all based on Metrics, Norms, Inner products, and operator theory by Christoper Heil. \\

As a sidenote, do you think the aforementioned exponential system is an ONB for $L^2[0,1]^d$

Comment: The system is indeed an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda, \mu\in \mathbb{Z}^d.$ Then $$\int\limits_{[0,1]^d} e^{i\pi\langle \lambda , x\rangle }e^{-i\pi\langle, \mu x\rangle }\,dx=\prod_{j=1}^d\int\limits_0^1 e^{i\pi x_j\lambda _j}e^{-i\pi x_j\mu _j}\,dx_j$$
If $\lambda=\mu$ we get $1.$ If $\lambda\neq \mu$ then $\lambda_j\neq \mu_j$ for some $j.$ Then the  integral with index $j$ vanishes. Thus we got orthonormality.

Next let $\mathcal{A}$ denote the linear span of the functions $[0,1]^d\ni x\mapsto e^{i\pi \langle x,\lambda\rangle }.$ Then $\mathcal{A}$ forms a subalgebra  in the space of $C_{per}([0,1]^d).$ The subalgebra is closed under complex conjugation as $\overline{e^{i\pi\langle x,\lambda\rangle }}=e^{i\pi\langle x, -\lambda\rangle}.$ It contains constants, as $e^{i\pi\langle x,0\rangle}=1,$ and separates points, as if $u\neq v\in [0,1)^d$ then $u_j\neq v_j$ for some $j.$ Then the function
$x\mapsto e^{i\pi x_j}$ gives different values at $u$ and $v.$
Therefore by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is uniformly dense in $C_{per}([0,1]^d).$ Furthermore $C_{per}([0,1]^d)$ is dense in $L^2([0,1]^d)$ with respect to $L^2$ norm. Thus $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $L^2([0,1]^d)$ with respect to $L^2$ norm. Hence $L^2([0,1]^d)$ does not contain a nonzero function orthogonal to all the functions $[0,1]^d\ni x\mapsto e^{i\pi \langle x,\lambda\rangle }.$

**Remark** Applying the Stone-Weierstrass theorem is a slight overkill. The proof can be performed by applying the Weierstrass theorem, or the Cesaro means, but it requires more explanations.

Comment: Great answer, reading it anew today it made a lot more sense. Could you however clarify a bit more what you mean with "Then $\mathcal{A}$ forms a subalgebra of in the space of $_{}([0,1]^)$, which does not vanish as $1 \in \mathcal{A}$

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I have re-edited. The Stone-Weierstrass theorem in the complex version requires the algebra is closed under complex conjugation, separates points and contains constants. The last condition can be weakened to nonvanishing property that for every point $x$ there is a function in $f\in A$ such that $f(x)\neq 0.$ If $A$ contains $1$ then $f(x)\equiv 1$ takes care of all points.